# Google Sheets - Repeat values 'n' times from a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to execute the following in google sheets by repeating certain cell values from a range of cells (number of repetitions) and iterating it horizontally till the end of the row.
[image: Desired Output and current result]

Formula used for current output:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(A1&",",A2:A4 ), ,999^99), ","))));ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(C1&",",C2:C4 ), ,999^99), ","))));ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(E1&",",E1:E4 ), ,999^99), ","))))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("×", 1, 
 REPT({A1&"×", C1&"×", E1&"×"}, {A2:A, C2:C, E2:E})), "×")))
```

[image]

shorter:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("×", 1, 
 REPT({A1, C1, E1}&"×", {A2:A, C2:C, E2:E})), "×")))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 REPT("×"&{A1, C1, E1}&"×", {A2:A, C2:C, E2:E})),,9^9)),,9^9), "×")), 
 "where not Col1 starts with ' '"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks player0. When I apply it to a larger data the Text result of textjoin exceeds the limit of 50000 characters.

Comment: the formulas fail when there are large number of repetitions. Could you be able to look into this and help. Sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jjuTLYp5c1rAPovR3b8DSAZmrc_0goEcV_IRGSbkEkw/

Comment: @Scitech I tweaked it a bit but the real culprit was 50k+ rows you had there `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS(I2:I&J2:J, I2:I&J2:J, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))=1, IFNA(VLOOKUP(I2:I&J2:J, SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&{B1,D1}&"×"&{C2:C,E2:E})), "×"), 2, )), ))`

Comment: '50K rows had to be inserted because "American Premier League 2022" has to be repeated 43,550 times, hence the extra rows. Under the Event column, the said event does not repeat even once because of the large repetitive number.